# How to configure Visual Studio 2012 be used without arrow keys?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to use Happy Hacking Keyboard, which has no arrow keys. But I'm not sure if I will be able to redefine Visual Studio keys to something other than arrow keys.

Also traditional Ctrl+HJKL keys are used by VS for some other important tasks.

What is a good way to stop using arrow keys in VS shortcuts?

Comment: There is no good way, selecting text can't be solved with just a keyboard key assignment.  You'll need macros or an add-in.  Happy??

Comment: @hans-passant, looks like that's the answer. Hoped for some kind of addon. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally love [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329). Changes the editor to be much like Vim, so `hjkl` replace your arrow keys. Works well with a lot of other plugins, is generally pretty stable, and updates often (much unlike ViEmu, a similar plugin).

If you don't want to use a plugin, you could attempt to remap all of the arrow keys, but I'm not sure if VS provides an option to remap editor commands like that.

Answer (score 0):

use the built in functionality
under (tools)
(options)
(keyboard)

Comment: This has no support for arrow keys. So you cannot say `CTRL`+`H` = `Arrow Left`